# Dependant modules to be installed while creating executable in cx_freeze

Tags: python-2.7, packaging, cx-freeze

I have created a python script which is dependant on the library speedtest-cli. Now I am packaging it to an executable. However I dont want to create a overhead to all the users using my script having to install speedtest-cli. How do I specify that in setup.py file so that speedtest-cli will automatically be installed while installing my exe.

And I am making it a standalone application.

```
from cx_Freeze import setup,Executable
import sys


includes = ["speedtest-cli"]

setup(name = "Bandwithtest",
      version = "1.0",
      options = {"build_exe" : {"includes" : includes}},
      executables = [Executable("networktest.py")]
```

Adding the module in includes doesnt work.It raises an import error.
ImportError :  No module named 'speedtest-cli'

I have 2 questions

1. How do I ensure speedtest-cli installs when users install my application?
2. I have also imported speedtest-cli in my module though I dont use it in my program. Ideally cx_freeze automatically bundles all the imported modules. But it didnt do so for speedtest-cli.Why is that so?

Here is the script am trying to freeze.

```
class Net(threading.Thread):

   def __init__(self, interval):
      threading.Thread.__init__(self)
      self.interval = interval

   def run(self):

      self.main()

   def main(self,interval):

      try:
        while thread1.is_alive():
           p = subprocess.Popen(r'speedtest-cli',
                              stdout = PIPE, 
                              stderr = PIPE)  #--> This is definitely required

   except KeyboardInterrupt as e:
         print "Exiting", e



class UI:

  def __init__(self,* args, **kwargs):        

     tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

     self.wm_title("Network Test")
     self.geometry('250x75')
     self.resizable(width = False, height = False)

     self.label = tk.Label(text = "Frequency(seconds)")
     self.label.grid(row = 0, column = 0)

     self.entry = tk.Entry(bd = 5)
     self.entry.grid(row = 0, column = 1)

     self.button = tk.Button(text = "Start Test", command = self.callthread)

     self.button.grid(row = 1, column = 0)

     self.button1 = tk.Button(text = "Stop Test")
     self.button1.grid(row = 1, column = 1)

     self.mainloop()

def callthread(self):

   thread2 = Net(self.entry.get())
   thread2.start()


if __name__ == "__main__":

   thread1 = threading.Thread(target = MyUI)
   thread1.start()
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: The setup should work the way you did it. Could you share the script you are trying to freeze?

Comment: @DanielePantaleone. Thanks for replying. I have updated the question with the script am trying to freeze. Also an additional info. I changed the speedtest-cli to speedtest_cli. It did not give any build errors.However it did not install the speedtest module as well.

Comment: @DanielePantaleone I think i almost found the reason for the problem. The speedtest_cli is an egg file. I believe cx_freeze cannot detect egg files. Is there a solution for this?